# Why does checkpoint node download fsimage and edits every time when creating a checkpoint?

Tags: hadoop, merge

In HDFS, as a Checkpoint node keeps the latest checkpoint of Namenode, When the Checkpoint node creating next checkpoint, it would download the `fsimage` and `edits` together, can someone explain that why not it just download the edits file and merge it with local fsimage in checkpoint node? or I had misunderstood it?